# How to create tables and columns in accumulo

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, accumulo

I am new to accumulo.I dont know how to create a table and also columns  in accumulo. can anyone suggest me with a sample how to create table and columns in accumulo. thanks in advance.

Comment: When I Google `How to create tables and columns in accumulo` it takes me to the Accumulo user manual which has a chapter on basic administration, including how to create a table, is that not helpful? How/why?

Comment: @pekka i found some information when i googled but i asked with a sample.and also i need how to create a column name.

Comment: Can you specify what part of the documentation you had a problem with, where you were stuck? That might yield some more responses

Comment: root@primary> createtable my_table .after this command i would like to create some columns like emp_id,emp_name and also emp_department.how can i create this columns.

Comment: I don't know this product but that may not be how Accumulo works. It appears to be some kind of [Bigtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable#Design) thing. Not sure - perhaps you're best off looking for an introductory tutorial first

Comment: ya you are right Accumulo was built on top of hadoop,zookeper and google bigTable.i searched for Accumulo tutorial but i  couldn't find any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to convert a relational table to Accumulo? That's fairly easy using the Primary Key as your row, then use the Field Name as your Column Family, leave the Column Qualifier blank and finally use the Field Value as your value.

There is no open source gui tool that I know of to view Accumulo data.

Answer (score 4):

I think you really need to re-read the user manual at https://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html

Accumulo doesn't have columns in the traditional sense of relational databases.  Instead of having lots of different columns in a table with a schema, you have rows, which have a ColumnQualifier and ColumnFamily.  This is a fairly significant difference from what you are trying to do.  Again, re-read the user document and then re-ask/reformat your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. we can see the data inserted in shell. Is there any workbench kind of tool available for accumulo to view the data persisted in accumulo.

Comment: You can use the web GUI to see stats about your tables and whatnot, but I don't know of any GUI tools off the top of my head for reading the tables.  Usually this is done via the shell or possibly programatically.